# AVPLayer in Swiftui resets when button is pressed

Tags: swiftui, avplayer

I have a video player and below it I have text for a title. When you tap on the text I have it increase in Font size. But when you increase the font size it causes the video to stop playing and restart. I don't want that to happen. I want the video to play unaffected by the font increase.
I'm very new to swiftUI fyi.

```
import SwiftUI
```

import AVKit

struct TEST: View {

```
@State private var tapped: Bool = false
@State private var draggedOffset = CGSize.zero
@State private var fontSize: CGFloat = 20 // Change Font Size

var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        
        VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "http://www.unisonprinting.com/0celot/dune/dune.mp4")!))
            .aspectRatio(3/2, contentMode: .fit)
        
        Text ("VIDEO TITLE")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.system(size: fontSize))
            .onTapGesture {
                if self.fontSize < 44 {
                    self.fontSize = self.fontSize + 12
                } else {
                    self.fontSize = 20
                }
            }
    }//V

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, each the the `View`'s body is rendered, a *new* `AVPlayer` is created, causing the video to stop playing and restart.

You can avoid this by storing the `AVPlayer` in a `@State` variable, which persists across renders:

```
struct TEST: View {
    
    @State private var tapped: Bool = false
    @State private var draggedOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var fontSize: CGFloat = 20 // Change Font Size
    
    @State private var player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://www.unisonprinting.com/0celot/dune/dune.mp4")!)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .aspectRatio(3/2, contentMode: .fit)
            
            Text ("VIDEO TITLE")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .font(.system(size: fontSize))
                .onTapGesture {
                    if self.fontSize < 44 {
                        self.fontSize = self.fontSize + 12
                    } else {
                        self.fontSize = 20
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Update, based on comments, showing one possible solution of how to have the `VideoPlayer` load a different `AVPlayer` based on a changing URL parameter:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var url : String = "https://www.unisonprinting.com/0celot/dune/dune.mp4"
    
    @State private var tapped: Bool = false
    @State private var draggedOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var fontSize: CGFloat = 20 // Change Font Size
    
    @State private var player : AVPlayer?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            if let player = player {
                VideoPlayer(player: player)
                    .aspectRatio(3/2, contentMode: .fit)
            }
            
            Text ("VIDEO TITLE")
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .font(.system(size: fontSize))
                .onTapGesture {
                    if self.fontSize < 44 {
                        self.fontSize = self.fontSize + 12
                    } else {
                        self.fontSize = 20
                    }
                }
        }
        .onAppear {
            setPlayerToUrl(url)
        }
        .onChange(of: url) { url in
            setPlayerToUrl(url)
        }
    }
    
    func setPlayerToUrl(_ url: String) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: url)!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but what if I want the URL to be a variable so it can be different URL's?

Comment: There are many possible solutions -- I added one as an update. You also could consider storing your URL *and* `AVPlayer` in an `ObservableObject` with `@Published` properties and using Combine to watch the changes/control updates, etc

Comment: Ok. What if I want to iterate through URL's using ForEach? I have a model with one of the properties being a URL string

Comment: @ReneRobles I'm not quite sure what you mean -- this view can definitely be used within a `ForEach`. Beyond that, I'd need more details. That being said, I believe I've answered the original question, plus the added requirement of changing the URL. If you feel the original question is answered, please consider marking it as correct with the green checkmark. If you feel it was helpful, you can upvote as well. I'm happy to answer other implementation questions as well, but it seems like the `ForEach` one *might* be suited to a new question.